# How do I implement tone() and noTone() for the Arduino Due?

Tags: c, arduino

As it turns out, [noTone()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/NoTone) and [tone()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone) are in the core arduino API, but [seemingly not implemented](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=139683.0) for the [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue).  I was hoping to use `tone()` and `noTone()` to implement the mario death sound found here, but when I add the code and compile it, I get the following errors:

> ```
> trenchRun:154: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope
> trenchRun:156: error: 'noTone' was not declared in this scope
> ```

In case you're interested, here's an SSCCE, compiled against Arduino 1.5.4 on Mac OS X 10.8:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  tone(1, 12345, 1000);
}
```

> ```
> sketch_oct24a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
> sketch_oct24a:7: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope
> ```

Since I have an Arduino Due, I am limited in using Arduino 1.5.4.

How do I implement the `tone()` and `noTone()` functions for the Due?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it seems that it is still disabled in the current version.

A quick search on the Arduino forum got me this : [Arduino Due and tone()](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-due-and-tone/133302)
I can't test their code but it seems that the guy found a pretty decent solution to make his own `tone()`.

Have a look and tell us if it's working good.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I can verify that his code working beautifully on the Arduino Due.

Comment: Hi, the link is broken, would you know an update link please?

Comment: @RM. link updated